# Type of "freeplay" (string) is not supported

Tags: json

I have a json file which looks like this

```
{
    "language":[
        {
            "lang":"English"
        },
        {
            "lang":"Polish"
        },
        {
            "lang":"German"
        },
        {
            "lang":"Swedish"
        },
        {
            "lang":"Dutch"
        },
        {
            "lang":"Finnish"
        },
        {
            "lang":"Turkish"
        }
    ],
    "currency":[
        {
            "curr" : "dollar"
        },
        {
            "curr" : "pound"
        },
        {
            "curr" : "rupees"
        },
        {
            "curr" : "euro"
        },
        {
            "curr" : "euro"
        }
    ],
    "gamename":[
        {
            "gname":"poker"
        },
        {
            "gname":"slot"
        }
    ],
    "freeplay": "false"
}
```

I installed `json-server-init` globally and then ran watch command which threw the following error

> Type of "freeplay" (string) in linkto.json is not supported. Use
>   objects or arrays of objects.

Can someone help me in understanding what is wrong or what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of `json-server`, the value of each key must be a valid JSON object, which is not the case for a simple string.

For example, change the value (contents of other keys omitted) to:

```
{
    "language":[
        ...
    ],
    "currency":[
        ...
    ],
    "gamename":[
        ...
    ],
    "freeplay": {
        "enabled": "false"
    }
}
```

if you'd like the request to:

http://localhost:3000/freeplay

to return:

```
{
    "enabled": "false"
}
```